# How can i add 1 day to a DateTime variable in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

What im trying to do is to add/sum a single day to an already declared DateTime variable.
For context i take the DateTime value from a user input and then I want to add/sum 1 day for comparison and query purposes.

This is what i had in mind but i know this method wont work.

```
SQL.AddParam("@FromDate", FromDate + 1)
```

What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: I commend to your attention the [.DateAdd() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.dateandtime.dateadd?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: You didnt try the obvious [`DateTime.AddDays`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.adddays?view=netcore-3.1)? Just use 1 as parameter: `FromDate.AddDays(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim dateTime As DateTime
dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(1)
```

Datetime objects provide some functions to add time.

```
.AddDays(days as Double)
.AddHours(hours as Double)
.AddMinutes(minutes as Double)
.AddSeconds(seconds as Double)
.AddMilliseconds(milliseconds as Double)
```

Or you can try to pass directly to SQL your date + 1 day.

```
SQL.AddParam("@FromDate", DateAdd(DateInterval.DayOfYear, 1, FromDate))
```

Datetime.DateAdd function Microsoft's documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.dateandtime.dateadd?view=netcore-3.1